# Using npm module basic_auth

Tags: node.js

I've a simple Node.js app where I'm exploring use of basic_auth npm module. The idea is to protect one route and it's content with simple authentication. 
Following is the code snippet from my application.

```
const basicAuth = require('basic-auth');
var auth = function(req, res, next) {
console.log('auth function');
function unauthorized(res) {
  res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm=Authorization Required');
  return res.send(401);
};

const user = basicAuth(req); //Incoming form with name and pass properties
if (!user || !user.name || !user.pass) {
  return unauthorized(res);
}

// authentication properties
const name = "foo";
const passcode = "123456";
if (user.name === name  && user.pass === passcode) {
  return next();
}
return unauthorized(res);
};

app.get('/protectedfile', auth, async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    res.sendfile('./public/boo.html');
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

When access this route from a browser "basic-auth" module module brings up a pop-up asking for username and password. Is there a way to restrict to ask only one property instead for example just an username?

Comment: Basic `auth` involves both the things password and the username. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: Thanks but I knew that. I still would like to know if there is any other way to achieve needed functionality either using basic-auth or something else.

Comment: No, i don't think there is a standard as such of what you want. You can keep the password an empty string at the very best.